# When pushing local Node.js project Git repo that has node_modules up to Heroku, do the local node_modules overwrite those on Heroku?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongoose

I want to understand better the relationship between the `node_modules` that are part of my Node project on my local machine and those that are part of my app that resides on Heroku.

When I'm building and testing a project locally (on my machine, using my `localhost`), I need to download various Node modules (e.g., `mongodb`, `mongoose`, `util`, `express`, and others). When I've tested my app locally, I want to push it up to the server. When I do the push, the `node_modules` folder also gets pushed up.

So what happens if I've already installed `MongoDB` (via the Heroku `MongoLab` Add-On) and `Mongoose` on Heroku through my account's/app's dashboard, and then I push my project up, which has a `node_modules` folder (containing `mongodb`)? Does my local `mongodb` `node_module` overwrite the module that was created using the `MongoLab` shell on Heroku? Or does Heroku ignore my push and preserve its version?

And what about the databases? Presumably the databases (local and Heroku) are completely isolated from each other, so there's no possibility of any conflict there. So I'm more interested to know what happens with the contents of the `node_modules`.

I know that you can set `.gitgnore` to ignore various things (like a `node_modules` folder), but then i lose the other modules my app needs, and it doesn't run. And I know you can selectively exclude certain folders. The question is whether I need to add any entries to my `.gitignore` to exclude things like MongoDB (and/or Mongoose).

Thanks in anticipation of a clarification.

Answer (score 2):

You should be putting adding your module dependencies in `package.json` and including `node_modules/` in your `.gitignore`.

With the dependencies listed in `package.json`, Heroku will download those packages every time you do a push and you can easily keep your dev environment in sync with your deployment environment.

The local MongoDB is independent of your Heroku MongoDB, however, if you want to setup your dev environment to access the Heroku MongoDB you can do so by pulling the environment variables from Heroku and putting them in `.env' like this:

```
heroku config -s > .env
```

Then you can launch your app with `foreman` and it will load the environment variables in your `.env`

```
foreman start
```

Then your dev app will connect to the same MongoDB instance that your Heroku app does.  This is useful if you keep a staging app on Heroku.

Comment: Hey Daniel - thank you for taking the time to reply; I appreciate it. Yes, I certainly do have a `package.json` file as part of my project. So you you're saying I can safely add a `node_modules/` entry to my `.gitignore`, and Heroku will download the needed modules - assuming my dependency list is current and accurate. That's great, makes complete sense, and simplifies things.

Useful to know about keeping only one instance of the DB on Heroku and linking to it locally; that'll prevent data from getting out of synch - thanks for that.