# Error pushing code on heroku Refusing to delete File exists move it away

Tags: node.js, heroku, github

There is no problem pushing code in github
Below is the text i get when i try to push code on heroku... (git push -f heroku master)
I have hosted many nodejs apps on heroku previously, never get any error like this before.

````
Counting objects: 446, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (402/402), done.
Writing objects: 100% (446/446), 446.25 KiB | 24 KiB/s, done.
Total 446 (delta 39), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Node.js app detected
-----> Resolving engine versions
       Using Node.js version: 0.8.25
       Using npm version: 1.1.65
-----> Fetching Node.js binaries
-----> Vendoring node into slug
-----> Installing dependencies with npm
npm WARN package.json node-js-sample@0.0.2 No README.md file found!
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/express
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express/-/express-3.3.4.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/express/-/express-3.3.4.tgz
npm ERR! Refusing to delete: /tmp/build_3w1dbtufk3ykl/node_modules/.bin/express not in /tmp/build_3w1dbtufk3ykl/node_modules/express
File exists: /tmp/build_3w1dbtufk3ykl/node_modules/.bin/express
Move it away, and try again. 

npm ERR! System Linux 3.8.11-ec2
npm ERR! command "/tmp/node-node-fVfm/bin/node" "/tmp/node-npm-NUWq/cli.js" "install" "--production"
npm ERR! cwd /tmp/build_3w1dbtufk3ykl
npm ERR! node -v v0.8.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.65
npm ERR! path /tmp/build_3w1dbtufk3ykl/node_modules/.bin/express
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/build_3w1dbtufk3ykl/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
 !     Failed to install --production dependencies with npm
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/tmp/node-node-fVfm/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/tmp/node-npm-NUWq/cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '--production' ]
2 info using npm@1.1.65
3 info using node@v0.8.25
4 verbose read json /tmp/build_3w1dbtufk3ykl/package.json
5 warn package.json node-js-sample@0.0.2 No README.md file found!
6 verbose readDependencies using package.json deps
7 verbose install where, deps [ '/tmp/build_3w1dbtufk3ykl', [ 'express' ] ]
8 verbose from cache /tmp/build_3w1dbtufk3ykl/package.json
9 info preinstall node-js-sample@0.0.2
10 verbose read json /tmp/build_3w1dbtufk3ykl/node_modules/express/package.json
11 verbose from cache /tmp/build_3w1dbtufk3ykl/package.json
12 verbose readDependencies using package.json deps
13 verbose read json /tmp/build_3w1dbtufk3ykl/node_modules/.bin/package.json
14 verbose from cache /tmp/build_3w1dbtufk3ykl/node_modules/express/package.json
15 verbose cache add [ 'express@~3.3.4', null ]
16 silly cache add name=undefined spec="express@~3.3.4" args=["express@~3.3.4",null]
17 verbose parsed url { pathname: 'express@~3.3.4',
17 verbose parsed url   path: 'express@~3.3.4',
17 verbose parsed url   href: 'express@~3.3.4' }
18 silly cache add name="express" spec="~3.3.4" args=["express","~3.3.4"]
19 verbose parsed url { pathname: '~3.3.4', path: '~3.3.4', href: '~3.3.4' }
20 verbose addNamed [ 'express', '~3.3.4' ]
21 verbose addNamed [ null, '>=3.3.4- <3.4.0-' ]
22 silly lockFile 09d41e23-express-3-3-4 express@~3.3.4
23 verbose lock express@~3.3.4 /tmp/build_3w1dbtufk3ykl/.npm/09d41e23-express-3-3-4.lock
24 silly addNameRange { name: 'express', range: '>=3.3.4- <3.4.0-', hasData: false }
25 verbose url raw express
26 verbose url resolving [ 'https://registry.npmjs.org/', './express' ]
27 verbose url resolved https://registry.npmjs.org/express
28 info trying registry request attempt 1 at 15:10:22
29 http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express
30 http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/express
31 silly registry.get cb [ 200,
31 silly registry.get   { vary: 'Accept',
31 silly registry.get     server: 'CouchDB/1.3.0 (Erlang OTP/R15B03)',
31 silly registry.get     etag: '"E8D4EVY5LHOO8X0N8RYQ5VEP0"',
31 silly registry.get     date: 'Wed, 24 Jul 2013 15:10:23 GMT',
31 silly registry.get     'content-type': 'application/json',
31 silly registry.get     'content-length': '393078' } ]
32 silly addNameRange number 2 { name: 'express', range: '>=3.3.4- <3.4.0-', hasData: true }
33 silly addNameRange versions [ 'express',
33 silly addNameRange   [ '0.14.0',
33 silly addNameRange     '0.14.1',
33 silly addNameRange     '1.0.0',
33 silly addNameRange     '1.0.1',
33 silly addNameRange     '1.0.2',
33 silly addNameRange     '1.0.3',
33 silly addNameRange     '1.0.4',
33 silly addNameRange     '1.0.5',
33 silly addNameRange     '1.0.6',
33 silly addNameRange     '1.0.7',
33 silly addNameRange     '1.0.8',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.0.0',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.1.0',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.1.1',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.2.0',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.2.1',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.2.2',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.3.0',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.3.1',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.3.2',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.3.3',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.3.4',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.3.5',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.3.6',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.3.7',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.3.8',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.3.9',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.3.10',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.3.11',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.3.12',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.4.0',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.4.1',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.4.2',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.4.3',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.4.4',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.4.5',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.4.6',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.4.7',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.5.0',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.5.1',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.5.2',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.5.3',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.5.4',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.5.5',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.5.6',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.5.7',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.5.8',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.5.9',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.5.10',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.5.11',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.0.0',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.0.1',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.0.2',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.0.3',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.0.4',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.0.5',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.0.6',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.1.0',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.1.1',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.1.2',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.2.0',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.2.1',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.2.2',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.2.3',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.2.4',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.2.5',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.2.6',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.3.0',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.3.1',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.3.2',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.3.3',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.3.4',
33 silly addNameRange     '1.0.0-beta',
33 silly addNameRange     '1.0.0-beta2',
33 silly addNameRange     '1.0.0-rc',
33 silly addNameRange     '1.0.0-rc2',
33 silly addNameRange     '1.0.0-rc3',
33 silly addNameRange     '1.0.0-rc4',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.0.0-beta',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.0.0-beta2',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.0.0-beta3',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.0.0-rc',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.0.0-rc2',
33 silly addNameRange     '2.0.0-rc3',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.0.0-alpha1',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.0.0-alpha2',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.0.0-alpha3',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.0.0-alpha4',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.0.0-alpha5',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.0.0-beta1',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.0.0-beta2',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.0.0-beta3',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.0.0-beta4',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.0.0-beta6',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.0.0-beta7',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.0.0-rc1',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.0.0-rc2',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.0.0-rc3',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.0.0-rc4',
33 silly addNameRange     '3.0.0-rc5' ] ]
34 verbose addNamed [ 'express', '3.3.4' ]
35 verbose addNamed [ '3.3.4', '3.3.4' ]
36 silly lockFile 536d637b-express-3-3-4 express@3.3.4
37 verbose lock express@3.3.4 /tmp/build_3w1dbtufk3ykl/.npm/536d637b-express-3-3-4.lock
38 silly lockFile f24d7c71-js-org-express-express-3-3-4-tgz https://registry.npmjs.org/express/-/express-3.3.4.tgz
39 verbose lock https://registry.npmjs.org/express/-/express-3.3.4.tgz /tmp/build_3w1dbtufk3ykl/.npm/f24d7c71-js-org-express-express-3-3-4-tgz.lock
40 verbose addRemoteTarball [ 'https://registry.npmjs.org/express/-/express-3.3.4.tgz',
40 verbose addRemoteTarball   '9abf22017213a8f6f54a421ce22b8ec27b7def62' ]
41 info retry fetch attempt 1 at 15:10:23
42 verbose fetch to= /tmp/build_3w1dbtufk3ykl/tmp/npm-620/1374678623471-0.6809613797813654/tmp.tgz
43 http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express/-/express-3.3.4.tgz
44 http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/express/-/express-3.3.4.tgz
45 silly shasum updated bytes 36094
46 info shasum 9abf22017213a8f6f54a421ce22b8ec27b7def62
46 info shasum /tmp/build_3w1dbtufk3ykl/tmp/npm-620/1374678623471-0.6809613797813654/tmp.tgz
47 verbose tar unpack /tmp/build_3w1dbtufk3ykl/tmp/npm-620/1374678623471-0.6809613797813654/tmp.tgz
48 silly lockFile 9de3180d-23471-0-6809613797813654-package /tmp/build_3w1dbtufk3ykl/tmp/npm-620/1374678623471-0.6809613797813654/package
49 verbose lock /tmp/build_3w1dbtufk3ykl/tmp/npm-620/1374678623471-0.6809613797813654/package /tmp/build_3w1dbtufk3ykl/.npm/9de3180d-23471-0-6809613797813654-package.lock
50 silly gunzTarPerm modes [ '755', '644' ]
51 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry package.json
52 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry .npmignore
53 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry LICENSE
54 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry index.js
55 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry test.js
56 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry .travis.yml
57 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry History.md
58 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry Makefile
59 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry bin/express
60 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry Readme.md
61 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry lib/application.js
62 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry lib/express.js
63 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry lib/middleware.js
64 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry lib/request.js
65 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry lib/response.js
66 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry lib/utils.js
67 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry lib/view.js
68 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry lib/router/index.js
69 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry lib/router/route.js
70 verbose read json /tmp/build_3w1dbtufk3ykl/tmp/npm-620/1374678623471-0.6809613797813654/package/package.json
71 silly lockFile 9de3180d-23471-0-6809613797813654-package /tmp/build_3w1dbtufk3ykl/tmp/npm-620/1374678623471-0.6809613797813654/package
72 verbose from cache /tmp/build_3w1dbtufk3ykl/tmp/npm-620/1374678623471-0.6809613797813654/package/package.json
73 verbose tar pack [ '/tmp/build_3w1dbtufk3ykl/.npm/express/3.3.4/package.tgz',
73 verbose tar pack   '/tmp/build_3w1dbtufk3ykl/tmp/npm-620/1374678623471-0.6809613797813654/package' ]
74 verbose tarball /tmp/build_3w1dbtufk3ykl/.npm/express/3.3.4/package.tgz
75 verbose folder /tmp/build_3w1dbtufk3ykl/tmp/npm-620/1374678623471-0.6809613797813654/package
76 silly lockFile cf1523eb-kl-npm-express-3-3-4-package-tgz /tmp/build_3w1dbtufk3ykl/.npm/express/3.3.4/package.tgz
77 verbose lock /tmp/build_3w1dbtufk3ykl/.npm/express/3.3.4/package.tgz /tmp/build_3w1dbtufk3ykl/.npm/cf1523eb-kl-npm-express-3-3-4-package-tgz.lock
78 silly lockFile cf1523eb-kl-npm-express-3-3-4-package-tgz /tmp/build_3w1dbtufk3ykl/.npm/express/3.3.4/package.tgz
79 silly lockFile a9e947c1-fk3ykl-npm-express-3-3-4-package /tmp/build_3w1dbtufk3ykl/.npm/express/3.3.4/package
80 verbose lock /tmp/build_3w1dbtufk3ykl/.npm/express/3.3.4/package /tmp/build_3w1dbtufk3ykl/.npm/a9e947c1-fk3ykl-npm-express-3-3-4-package.lock
81 silly lockFile a9e947c1-fk3ykl-npm-express-3-3-4-package /tmp/build_3w1dbtufk3ykl/.npm/express/3.3.4/package
82 verbose tar unpack /tmp/build_3w1dbtufk3ykl/.npm/express/3.3.4/package.tgz
83 silly lockFile a9e947c1-fk3ykl-npm-express-3-3-4-package /tmp/build_3w1dbtufk3ykl/.npm/express/3.3.4/package
84 verbose lock /tmp/build_3w1dbtufk3ykl/.npm/express/3.3.4/package /tmp/build_3w1dbtufk3ykl/.npm/a9e947c1-fk3ykl-npm-express-3-3-4-package.lock
85 silly gunzTarPerm modes [ '755', '644' ]
86 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry package.json
87 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry .npmignore
88 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry LICENSE
89 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry index.js
90 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry test.js
91 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry .travis.yml
92 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry Readme.md
93 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry Makefile
94 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry lib/request.js
95 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry lib/middleware.js
96 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry lib/utils.js
97 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry lib/response.js
98 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry lib/application.js
99 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry lib/view.js
100 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry lib/express.js
101 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry lib/router/index.js
102 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry lib/router/route.js
103 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry bin/express
104 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry History.md
105 verbose read json /tmp/build_3w1dbtufk3ykl/.npm/express/3.3.4/package/package.json
106 silly lockFile a9e947c1-fk3ykl-npm-express-3-3-4-package /tmp/build_3w1dbtufk3ykl/.npm/express/3.3.4/package
107 silly shasum updated bytes 35463
108 info shasum e6e492337ddd9e87fa257208f8e864769bea7eef
108 info shasum /tmp/build_3w1dbtufk3ykl/.npm/express/3.3.4/package.tgz
109 verbose from cache /tmp/build_3w1dbtufk3ykl/.npm/express/3.3.4/package/package.json
110 verbose chmod /tmp/build_3w1dbtufk3ykl/.npm/express/3.3.4/package.tgz 644
111 verbose chown /tmp/build_3w1dbtufk3ykl/.npm/express/3.3.4/package.tgz [ 7564, 7564 ]
112 silly lockFile f24d7c71-js-org-express-express-3-3-4-tgz https://registry.npmjs.org/express/-/express-3.3.4.tgz
113 silly lockFile 536d637b-express-3-3-4 express@3.3.4
114 silly lockFile 09d41e23-express-3-3-4 express@~3.3.4
115 silly resolved [ { name: 'express',
115 silly resolved     description: 'Sinatra inspired web development framework',
115 silly resolved     version: '3.3.4',
115 silly resolved     author: { name: 'TJ Holowaychuk', email: 'tj@vision-media.ca' },
115 silly resolved     contributors: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
115 silly resolved     dependencies:
115 silly resolved      { connect: '2.8.4',
115 silly resolved        commander: '1.2.0',
115 silly resolved        'range-parser': '0.0.4',
115 silly resolved        mkdirp: '0.3.5',
115 silly resolved        cookie: '0.1.0',
115 silly resolved        'buffer-crc32': '0.2.1',
115 silly resolved        fresh: '0.1.0',
115 silly resolved        methods: '0.0.1',
115 silly resolved        send: '0.1.3',
115 silly resolved        'cookie-signature': '1.0.1',
115 silly resolved        debug: '*' },
115 silly resolved     devDependencies:
115 silly resolved      { ejs: '*',
115 silly resolved        mocha: '*',
115 silly resolved        jade: '0.30.0',
115 silly resolved        hjs: '*',
115 silly resolved        stylus: '*',
115 silly resolved        should: '*',
115 silly resolved        'connect-redis': '*',
115 silly resolved        marked: '*',
115 silly resolved        supertest: '0.6.0' },
115 silly resolved     keywords:
115 silly resolved      [ 'express',
115 silly resolved        'framework',
115 silly resolved        'sinatra',
115 silly resolved        'web',
115 silly resolved        'rest',
115 silly resolved        'restful',
115 silly resolved        'router',
115 silly resolved        'app',
115 silly resolved        'api' ],
115 silly resolved     repository: { type: 'git', url: 'git://github.com/visionmedia/express' },
115 silly resolved     main: 'index',
115 silly resolved     bin: { express: './bin/express' },
115 silly resolved     scripts: { prepublish: 'npm prune', test: 'make test' },
115 silly resolved     engines: { node: '*' },
115 silly resolved     readme: '![express logo](http://f.cl.ly/items/0V2S1n0K1i3y1c122g04/Screen%20Shot%202012-04-11%20at%209.59.42%20AM.png)\n\n  Fast, unopinionated, minimalist web framework for [node](http://nodejs.org). [![Build Status](https://secure.travis-ci.org/visionmedia/express.png)](http://travis-ci.org/visionmedia/express) [![Dependency Status](https://gemnasium.com/visionmedia/express.png)](https://gemnasium.com/visionmedia/express)\n\n```js\nvar express = require(\'express\');\nvar app = express();\n\napp.get(\'/\', function(req, res){\n  res.send(\'Hello World\');\n});\n\napp.listen(3000);\n```\n\n## Installation\n\n    $ npm install -g express\n\n## Quick Start\n\n The quickest way to get started with express is to utilize the executable `express(1)` to generate an application as shown below:\n\n Create the app:\n\n    $ npm install -g express\n    $ express /tmp/foo && cd /tmp/foo\n\n Install dependencies:\n\n    $ npm install\n\n Start the server:\n\n    $ node app\n\n## Features\n\n  * Built on [Connect](http://github.com/senchalabs/connect)\n  * Robust routing\n  * HTTP helpers (redirection, caching, etc)\n  * View system supporting 14+ template engines\n  * Content negotiation\n  * Focus on high performance\n  * Environment based configuration\n  * Executable for generating applications quickly\n  * High test coverage\n\n## Philosophy\n\n  The Express philosophy is to provide small, robust tooling for HTTP servers. Making\n  it a great solution for single page applications, web sites, hybrids, or public\n  HTTP APIs.\n\n  Built on Connect you can use _only_ what you need, and nothing more, applications\n  can be as big or as small as you like, even a single file. Express does\n  not force you to use any specific ORM or template engine. With support for over\n  14 template engines via [Consolidate.js](http://github.com/visionmedia/consolidate.js)\n  you can quickly craft your perfect framework.\n\n## More Information\n\n  * Join #express on freenode\n  * [Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/express-js) for discussion\n  * Follow [tjholowaychuk](http://twitter.com/tjholowaychuk) on twitter for updates\n  * Visit the [Wiki](http://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki)\n  * [Русскоязычная документация](http://jsman.ru/express/)\n  * Run express examples [online](https://runnable.com/express)\n\n## Viewing Examples\n\nClone the Express repo, then install the dev dependencies to install all the example / test suite deps:\n\n    $ git clone git://github.com/visionmedia/express.git --depth 1\n    $ cd express\n    $ npm install\n\nthen run whichever tests you want:\n\n    $ node examples/content-negotiation\n\n## Running Tests\n\nTo run the test suite first invoke the following command within the repo, installing the development dependencies:\n\n    $ npm install\n\nthen run the tests:\n\n    $ make test\n\n## Contributors\n\n```\nproject: express\ncommits: 3559\nactive : 468 days\nfiles  : 237\nauthors:\n 1891\tTj Holowaychuk          53.1%\n 1285\tvisionmedia             36.1%\n  182\tTJ Holowaychuk          5.1%\n   54\tAaron Heckmann          1.5%\n   34\tcsausdev                1.0%\n   26\tciaranj                 0.7%\n   21\tRobert Sköld            0.6%\n    6\tGuillermo Rauch         0.2%\n    3\tDav Glass               0.1%\n    3\tNick Poulden            0.1%\n    2\tRandy Merrill           0.1%\n    2\tBenny Wong              0.1%\n    2\tHunter Loftis           0.1%\n    2\tJake Gordon             0.1%\n    2\tBrian McKinney          0.1%\n    2\tRoman Shtylman          0.1%\n    2\tBen Weaver              0.1%\n    2\tDave Hoover             0.1%\n    2\tEivind Fjeldstad        0.1%\n    2\tDaniel Shaw             0.1%\n    1\tMatt Colyer             0.0%\n    1\tPau Ramon               0.0%\n    1\tPero Pejovic            0.0%\n    1\tPeter Rekdal Sunde      0.0%\n    1\tRaynos                  0.0%\n    1\tTeng Siong Ong          0.0%\n    1\tViktor Kelemen          0.0%\n    1\tctide                   0.0%\n    1\t8bitDesigner            0.0%\n    1\tisaacs                  0.0%\n    1\tmgutz                   0.0%\n    1\tpikeas                  0.0%\n    1\tshuwatto                0.0%\n    1\ttstrimple               0.0%\n    1\tewoudj                  0.0%\n    1\tAdam Sanderson          0.0%\n    1\tAndrii Kostenko         0.0%\n    1\tAndy Hiew               0.0%\n    1\tArpad Borsos            0.0%\n    1\tAshwin Purohit          0.0%\n    1\tBenjen                  0.0%\n    1\tDarren Torpey           0.0%\n    1\tGreg Ritter             0.0%\n    1\tGregory Ritter          0.0%\n    1\tJames Herdman           0.0%\n    1\tJim Snodgrass           0.0%\n    1\tJoe McCann              0.0%\n    1\tJonathan Dumaine        0.0%\n    1\tJonathan Palardy        0.0%\n    1\tJonathan Zacsh          0.0%\n    1\tJustin Lilly            0.0%\n    1\tKen Sato                0.0%\n    1\tMaciej Małecki          0.0%\n    1\tMasahiro Hayashi        0.0%\n```\n\n## License\n\n(The MIT License)\n\nCopyright (c) 2009-2012 TJ Holowaychuk &lt;tj@vision-media.ca&gt;\n\nPermission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining\na copy of this software and associated documentation files (the\n\'Software\'), to deal in the Software without restriction, including\nwithout limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish,\ndistribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to\npermit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to\nthe following conditions:\n\nThe above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be\nincluded in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.\n\nTHE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED \'AS IS\', WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,\nEXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF\nMERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT.\nIN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY\nCLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT,\nTORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE\nSOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.\n',
115 silly resolved     readmeFilename: 'Readme.md',
115 silly resolved     _id: 'express@3.3.4',
115 silly resolved     dist: { shasum: 'e6e492337ddd9e87fa257208f8e864769bea7eef' },
115 silly resolved     _from: 'express@~3.3.4' } ]
116 info install express@3.3.4 into /tmp/build_3w1dbtufk3ykl
117 info installOne express@3.3.4
118 verbose from cache /tmp/build_3w1dbtufk3ykl/.npm/express/3.3.4/package/package.json
119 info /tmp/build_3w1dbtufk3ykl/node_modules/express unbuild
120 verbose from cache /tmp/build_3w1dbtufk3ykl/node_modules/express/package.json
121 info preuninstall express@3.0.5
122 info uninstall express@3.0.5
123 verbose true,/tmp/build_3w1dbtufk3ykl/node_modules,/tmp/build_3w1dbtufk3ykl/node_modules unbuild express@3.0.5
124 verbose /tmp/build_3w1dbtufk3ykl/node_modules/.bin,[object Object] binRoot
125 info /tmp/build_3w1dbtufk3ykl/node_modules/express unbuild
126 verbose read json /tmp/build_3w1dbtufk3ykl/node_modules/express/package.json
127 info preuninstall express@3.0.5
128 info uninstall express@3.0.5
129 verbose true,/tmp/build_3w1dbtufk3ykl/node_modules,/tmp/build_3w1dbtufk3ykl/node_modules unbuild express@3.0.5
130 verbose /tmp/build_3w1dbtufk3ykl/node_modules/.bin,[object Object] binRoot
131 info postuninstall express@3.0.5
132 error Refusing to delete: /tmp/build_3w1dbtufk3ykl/node_modules/.bin/express not in /tmp/build_3w1dbtufk3ykl/node_modules/express
File exists: /tmp/build_3w1dbtufk3ykl/node_modules/.bin/express
Move it away, and try again.
133 error System Linux 3.8.11-ec2
134 error command "/tmp/node-node-fVfm/bin/node" "/tmp/node-npm-NUWq/cli.js" "install" "--production"
135 error cwd /tmp/build_3w1dbtufk3ykl
136 error node -v v0.8.25
137 error npm -v 1.1.65
138 error path /tmp/build_3w1dbtufk3ykl/node_modules/.bin/express
139 error code EEXIST
140 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app

To git@heroku.com:talha-webrtc.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:talha-webrtc.git'
````

package.json

```
    {
  "name": "node-example",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "2.5.x",
    "rest":"0.9.3"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.8.x",
    "npm": "1.1.x"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be solved by changing the cache behaviour on heroku as described [in their docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#cache-behavior):

`heroku config:set NODE_MODULES_CACHE=false`

Answer (score 0):

Try putting node_modules in your .gitignore. More info here: [When pushing local Node.js project Git repo that has node_modules up to Heroku, do the local node_modules overwrite those on Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17002124/when-pushing-local-node-js-project-git-repo-that-has-node-modules-up-to-heroku)

I also recommend reading up on npm shrinkwrap, to ensure dev/prod parity.